# Can i delete a statically defined variable using delete operator?

Tags: c++

Let us suppose I define an integer variable in C++. Can I delete the variable using delete operator after a few commands?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: I smell homework ;)

Comment: if you mean something like `int val; val = 42; delete val;` then no. If not, then your question needs expansion.

Comment: You can only `delete` an object that was allocated with `new`. Anything else is an error.

Comment: In a mirror to the placement new operator, you can directly use the object's destructor (however, the memory itself is not associated with a heap so cannot be `free`d, it just doesn't make sense).

Comment: @Petar, it's no homework

Comment: @user4581301 yes that is what I meant and thanks